# How to do Delphi-like frames in C#?

Tags: c#, delphi, frames

Slight bit of background: I'm a Delphi programmer re-learning C# (learned in school originally, haven't hardly touched until recently), and am trying to get some of my Delphi concepts transferred over.

The current situation is, I need to create an application that can use data from a variable list of similar data controls depending on location, need, etc. and in order to display that information in Delphi, I would simply use a scroll box and frames.  The scroll box I can easily replace with the C# panel class, but I'm not finding anything I can use that will tell me how to create my frame class for use inside the panel.  All I can find is some stuff for web development.

Can anyone point me in a good direction for learning the C# frame equivalent? Thanks.

EDIT:

For non-Delphi programmers, a frame is a form-like control that allows other controls (buttons, boxes, grids, etc) to be placed on it, then the frame gets used as a control itself on a form to reduce code-reuse as all frames do similar functionality and streamline development.  For a (probably better) more in-depth description, see [about.com's](http://delphi.about.com/b/2005/02/13/visual-delphi-development-using-frames.htm) or [Delphi Basics](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=Standard) descriptions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> EDIT:
>
> For non-Delphi programmers, a frame is
>   a form-like control that allows other
>   controls (buttons, boxes, grids, etc)
>   to be placed on it, then the frame
>   gets used as a control itself on a
>   form to reduce code-reuse as all
>   frames do similar functionality and
>   streamline development. For a
>   (probably better) more in-depth
>   description, see about.com's or Delphi
>   Basics descriptions.

Sounds like a User Control to me.

Here are some tutorials:

[WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294992.aspx)

[WinForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx)

Comment: Yup, looks like the exact equivalent.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Having used both Delphi and .Net, I think a [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx) is the equivalent.  It's a container that you can add controls to, and then add to other forms in the project.

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a custom control that extends the Panel class and then repeat that custom control.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Delphi, but what you describe sounds a bit like a WPF [FlowDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.aspx), or one of the related controls.

Comment: FlowDocument isn't quite what I need.  Will try to update question to better describe for non-Delphi users.  Thanks Though.

Answer (score 1):

Any Panel provides the same functionality as Delphi's Frame (a composite containing other controls).

To encapsulate and reuse a panel with specific children, you need to write a custom class (custom control (as Payton mentioned) in WinForms or better yet a new Control in WPF).

I also programmed in Delphi many years ago and I highly recommend using WPF and not WinForms, especially if you are familiar with HTML or XML or you need to write dynamic or data oriented applications.